# MobileFirst: make an adapter from wsdl file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

We are starting to used MobileFirst in our company. How do I make an adapter from a WSDL file?

Comment: Make an effort to read the documentation, attempt to do the work yourself, and then if you have a specific problem with which you need help, ask a revised question here on stack overflow which contains details on what you tried, what problem you are encountering, and what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation in [HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/server-side-development/http-adapter-communicating-http-back-end-systems/).
Search for "Back-end service discovery" and follow the instructions.

You can read more [in this Knowledge Center topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_using_service_discovery_to_explore_back-end_services.html).